# Moveable UserControl, deactivate slide out?

Tags: c#, user-controls, window, move, slide

i found this CodeSnipped the WWW. Im okay with the function of this snipped but my only Problem is that, when you move a UserControl you can move the Control out of the Window, its possible to deactivate this?

```
public void MakeDraggable(System.Windows.UIElement moveThisElement, System.Windows.UIElement movedByElement)
{
    bool isMousePressed = false;
    System.Windows.Media.TranslateTransform transform = new System.Windows.Media.TranslateTransform(0, 0);
    moveThisElement.RenderTransform = transform;
    System.Windows.Point originalPoint = new System.Windows.Point(0, 0), currentPoint;

    movedByElement.MouseLeftButtonDown += (a, b) =>
    {
           isMousePressed = true;
           originalPoint = ((System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs)b).GetPosition(moveThisElement);
    };

    movedByElement.MouseLeftButtonUp += (a, b) => isMousePressed = false;

    movedByElement.MouseLeave += (a, b) => isMousePressed = false;

    movedByElement.MouseMove += (a, b) =>
    {
           if (!isMousePressed) return;

           currentPoint = ((System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs)b).GetPosition(moveThisElement);

           transform.X += currentPoint.X - originalPoint.X;
           transform.Y += currentPoint.Y - originalPoint.Y;
    };
}
```

Thanks for your Help,
Fridolin

Comment: Before changing transform `X` and `Y`, check bounds, only change them, if control still fits the window.

Comment: Thanks for that answer but i really dont know how, cause i never done something with this kind of stuff :/